# JavaScript crypto.randomBytes(8) to Python Code

Tags: javascript, python

I am working with Python in an API. The API is coded using Javascript, and I do not know how would be the equivalent code of this line in Python:

```
crypto.randomBytes(8).join("")
```

I found out this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html, but I do not know what to do to get exactly the same result.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This should be `name="{{opcion}}"` and  remove `javascript:` in `onclick` and modify this `getElementById('{{opicon}}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from random import randint
bytes([randint(0, 255) for _ in range(8)])
```

**EDIT:** If you need secure random bytes:

```py
from secrets import token_bytes
token_bytes(8)
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes)